# Ansible fails with runuser: command not found

Tags: postgresql, path, ansible

I am trying to provision a PostgreSQL server using role [galaxyproject.postgresql](https://galaxy.ansible.com/galaxyproject/postgresql). Using Vagrant box `generic/centos7` this role fails with message

```
TASK [galaxyproject.postgresql : Initialize database (RedHat >= 7)] ************
fatal: [postgresql]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/postgresql96-setup", "initdb"], "delta": "0:00:00.181409", "end": "2019-10-16 01:45:59.495713", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2019-10-16 01:45:59.314304", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "Initializing database ... failed, see /var/lib/pgsql/9.6/initdb.log", "stdout_lines": ["Initializing database ... failed, see /var/lib/pgsql/9.6/initdb.log"]}
```

The file `/var/lib/pgsql/9.6/initdb.log` has the following message

```
/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/postgresql96-setup: line 143: runuser: command not found
```

On the target node `runuser` is available

```
[root@postgresql ~]# which runuser
/sbin/runuser
```

So the problem seems to be that `/sbin` is not on the `PATH` when Ansible runs on target nodes.

How can I make `runuser` command available to Ansible? I don't want to change the external role `galaxyproject.postgresql` of course.

When I output `PATH` using Ansible debug it shows that `PATH` does not include sbin.

```
TASK [galaxyproject.postgresql : debug] ****************************************
ok: [postgresql] => {
    "PATH": {
        "changed": true, 
        "cmd": "echo $PATH", 
        "delta": "0:00:00.010478", 
        "end": "2019-10-16 02:12:14.882341", 
        "failed": false, 
        "rc": 0, 
        "start": "2019-10-16 02:12:14.871863", 
        "stderr": "", 
        "stderr_lines": [], 
        "stdout": "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin", 
        "stdout_lines": [
            "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you run the command manually on the target host with the same user as your playbook ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add something into PATH, you can try to set environment for this module. I hadn't tried this for postgres module, but it should work:

```
- postgres_user: # or other module name you are using
     user: foo # and other normal arguments
  environment:
     PATH: '$PATH:/sbin'
```

See also: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_environment.html